# Insert rows into tables using OData POST

Tags: post, odata, hana, sapui5

What is the standard method to insert data into a table, update a table, delete rows in a table using OData? My front end is SAP UI5 and the tables are stored on a HANA SYSTEM. Do i have to use a POST request and the use OData.create ?

I have as of now only exposed a table through the xsodata file and used the GET method for the Http request to display the records.

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge, it is not yet supported for an INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operation. The OData service is currently read-only as laid out [here](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2012/11/29/sap-hana-extended-application-services). You can of course create a workaround by writing a server-side Javascript that basically issues a SQL query from your GET request like [this](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-33902) example.

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile XS OData supports writing data. You can even add your validation logic before data is written to the database. Check the developer guide at help.sap.com/hana for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a POST to make either to do an Insert, a PUT to do the update and DELETE to remove the data.

On the ui5 side you need to attach the table to a model(ie. the URL of the table you are trying to call) and do a model.refresh() for your changes to be updated in the table.